# Android HorizontalScrolling laggy

Tags: android, scroll, horizontalscrollview

I have a HorzontalScrollView with a LinearLayout inside. During Runtime I can add more LinearLayouts to the LinearLayout.

Now I have the problem that the Scrollview only scrolls a little bit and not smooth with one finger slide!

Does anyone have a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

HorizontalScrollView doesn't use an adapter that manages the list's memory, therefore it can't handle heavy (images, custom views, etc) lists.

You can use this Horizontal ListView http://www.dev-smart.com/archives/34 but make sure you don't write the on list item click method inside the getView, it will make the list scroll slow. Other than that, that's a great resource for a smooth horizontal list view.

You can also explore the Android view pager, which is also supported on lower Android versions using the compatibility pack: http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html

Edit - something like that in the adapter that inflates the XML you want (the linearLayout) and then populates every view with the relevant data.

```
    @Override
            public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

                if (convertView == null) {
                    convertView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.chat_friends_list_item, null);
                }

                ImageView status = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.status);
                ImageView image = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.image);
                ImageView imageBorder = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.image_border);
                TextView title = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
}
```

Comment: do you know how i can accomplish that if no element is inside the listview, a different linearlayout element with the whole width will be added to the listview?

Comment: @matchi1992 in the listview adapter's getview, populate the linear layout element XML. See updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was my parent Viewflow because it has stolen the swipe event! The HorizontalListView is too buggy for me! (Problems with size attributes)

However,thank you for your answer! ;)